# Raiz quadrada e número ao cubo numa table

Tags: php, html

Estou a aprender PHP e tenho um trabalho em que tenho que fazer a raiz quadrada e o cubo dos números de 1 a 10, exibindo em uma tabela com PHP.
Já consegui por a raiz quadrada dos números de 1 a 10 todos num quadrado e o mesmo com o cubo, mas para montar a tabela no PHP, não está dando certo. Tenho de usar o laço `for`. Como é que posso separar cada raiz e cubo do número a seguir?

Usei este código:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table border=1>
      <tr>
        <th>Cube</th>    
        <th>Square root</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>    
        <td>
          <?php
            //Cube 
            for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
              echo "$i^3 = ". pow($i,3) . "<br />";
            }
          ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php
            //Square Root
            for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
              echo "√$i = ".sqrt($i) . "<br />";
            }
          ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode armazená-los num array

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
    $rs['cube'][$i] = pow($i,3);
    $rs['sqrt'][$i] = sqrt($i);
}
?>
```

Com isso poderá manipular os dados como deseja.

Mas não está muito claro qual o resultado deseja no HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que o que você quer é isso:

```php
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Raiz quadradas e cubos</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>n</th>
        <th>Cube</th>    
        <th>Square root</th>
      </tr>
      <?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo "$i^3 = " . pow($i, 3); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo "√$i = " . sqrt($i); ?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ou seja, se você quer construir linhas da tabela em HTML, o seu `for` deve iterar as linhas, e não os valores individuais de cada coluna.

Além disso, note que não precisa acrescentar `<br />` dentro das células da sua tabela.

[Veja funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/wOOL2I)